# sonata admin add richhtml editor to block content

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I'd like to add ckeditor to content field in block admin.
Here's what i did till now:

1. added raw_content and content_formatter properties to my block
2. modified buildEditForm in TextBlockService to this:

   ```
   public function buildEditForm(FormMapper $formMapper, BlockInterface $block)
   {
   $formMapper->add('settings', 'sonata_type_immutable_array', array(
       'keys' => array(
           array('content', 'sonata_formatter_type', array(
               'event_dispatcher' => $formMapper->getformBuilder()->getEventDispatcher(),
               'format_field'   => ['content_formatter'],
               'source_field'   => ['raw_content'],
               'source_field_options'      => array(
                   'attr' => array('class' => 'span10', 'rows' => 10)
               ),
               'listener'       => true,
               'target_field'   => ['content']
           )),
       )
   ));
   }
   ```

It works just fine, allowing me to choose 'richhtml' from editors list but when i try to save the block it throws an error:

```
Expected argument of type "string or Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyPathInterface", "NULL" given
```

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's how it should be to work:

```
$formMapper->add('settings', 'ckeditor', array());
```